# NativeScript: custom Splash screen with random image

Tags: javascript, java, android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

How can I make custom splash screen for NativeScript application? I mean, custom java class (Activity), that will be shown while framework is loading.

To be exact, I want to display randomly one of the images from assets directory, different at each launch. Default NativeScript configuration only allows to specify one predefined logo.

Comment: Hey, does your application runs on JVM?

Comment: Did you check [nativescript-splashscreen](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-splashscreen/) plugin?